# How to compare two chi square results?

Tags: statistics, compare, chi-squared

I've got 2 STATA chi square outputs describing the frequencies of a worker's sex and industry of employment. The first chi square is for a sample of college graduates and the second sample consists of people who have been certified by some vocational program. They both show a Pr=0.000.

College grads had a Pearson chi2(14) = 123.5285 and a Cramer's V = 0.2606. 
Certified workers had a Pearson chi2(15) = 437.7627 and a Cramer's V = 0.4837.

I'm trying to figure out if these two distributions are (statistically) significantly different from each other. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to compare two different distributions of which you do not have the functional relationship (e.g. given by a theory), just the histograms. Your hypothesis is that for both variables (worker's sex and industry) relative frequencies follow the same model, but you do care what probability distribution that might be. The [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) would be a good approach to tackle that issue.

There is a nice [R blog describing how to approach the comparison of two distribution](https://thebiobucket.blogspot.com/2011/08/comparing-two-distributions.html). Even if that is not necessarily your programming language, it might be helpful. Here, the hypothesis is a slight different one, namely that he hypothesis is that one distribution  higher y-values than the other. Nevertheless, the structured approach might help you.

#### Further Reading

- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222294/understanding-kolmogorov-smirnov-test-in-r